# tensorflow import error: No module named tensorflow.python.checkpoint

Tags: python, tensorflow, import, package, importerror

i'm trying to import tensorflow-hub and i'm getting an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.checkpoint'
```

[full error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cakj.png)

Apparently the folder tensorflow.python.checkpoint doesn't exist in the tensorflow source code that I installed (though it does exist in the github repository of tensorflow)

I'm using

```
tensorflow                         2.9.1
tensorflow-estimator               2.9.0
tensorflow-hub                     0.8.0
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's probably not a permanent solution, but I think downgrading TensforFlow to version 1.15 should help